# Set HADOOP_CLASSPATH while using Spring jar-tasklet

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-xd

I am using hadoop jar-tasklet:

```
<hdp:jar-tasklet id="testjob" jar="bhs_abhishek.jar">
</hdp:jar-tasklet>
```

This jar currently needs some config files on classpath which I was earlier setting through `HADAOOP_CLASSPATH` variable for invocation through hadoop jar command. But I could not find a way of setting `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` using spring `xml`. Please provide any suggestions on how this can be achieved or a better way of doing this. I am OK to make changes in jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your config files to xd/config directory which should be on the classpath.

There is also a xd/config/hadoop-site.xml file where you could add Hadoop config properties. One more alternative is to modify xd/config/servers.yml and add Hadoop config properties under `spring:hadoop:config:` like we do for `io.file.buffer.size` in this example:

```
---
# Hadoop properties
spring:
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://hadoop.example.com:8020
    resourceManagerHost: hadoop.example.com
    resourceManagerPort: 8032
    jobHistoryAddress: hadoop.example.com:10020
    config:
      io.file.buffer.size: 4096

---
```